# How to not rebuild artifacts on every invocation

Tags: bazel

I want to download and build ruby within a workspace.  I've been trying to implement this by mimicking rules_go.  I have that part working.  The issue I'm having is it rebuilds the openssl and ruby artifacts each time `ruby_download_sdk` is invoked.  In the code below the download artifacts are cached but the builds of openssl and ruby are always executed.

```py
def ruby_download_sdk(name, version = None):
    # TODO detect os and arch
    os, arch = "osx", "x86_64"

    _ruby_download_sdk(
        name = name, 
        version = version,
    )
    _register_toolchains(name, os, arch)

def _ruby_download_sdk_impl(repository_ctx):
    # TODO detect platform
    platform = ("osx", "x86_64")

    _sdk_build_file(repository_ctx, platform)
    _remote_sdk(repository_ctx)

_ruby_download_sdk = repository_rule(
    _ruby_download_sdk_impl,
    attrs = {
        "version": attr.string(),
    },
)

def _remote_sdk(repository_ctx):
    _download_openssl(repository_ctx, version = "1.1.1c")
    _download_ruby(repository_ctx, version = "2.6.3")

    openssl_path, ruby_path = "openssl/build", ""
    _build(repository_ctx, "openssl", openssl_path, ruby_path)
    _build(repository_ctx, "ruby", openssl_path, ruby_path)

def _build(repository_ctx, name, openssl_path, ruby_path):
    script_name = "build-{}.sh".format(name)
    template_name = "build-{}.template".format(name)

    repository_ctx.template(
        script_name,
        Label("@rules_ruby//ruby/private:{}".format(template_name)),
        substitutions = {
            "{ssl_build}": openssl_path,
            "{ruby_build}": ruby_path,
        }
    )
    repository_ctx.report_progress("Building {}".format(name))
    res = repository_ctx.execute(["./" + script_name], timeout=20*60)

    if res.return_code != 0:
        print("res %s" % res.return_code)
        print(" -stdout: %s" % res.stdout)
        print(" -stderr: %s" % res.stderr)
```

Any advice on how I can make bazel aware such that it doesn't rebuild these build artifacts every time?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that bazel isn't really building your ruby and openssl. When it prepares your build tree and runs the repository rule, it just executes a shell script as instructed, which apparently happens to build, but that fact is essentially opaque to bazel (and it also happens before bazel itself would even build).

There might be other, but I see the following as your options from top of my head:

- Pre-build your ruby environment and its results as external dependency. The obvious downside (which may or may not be quite a lot of pain) being you need to do so for all platforms you need to supports (incl. making sure correct detection and corresponding download). The upside being you really only build once (per platform) and also have control over tooling used across all hosts. This would likely be my primary choice.
- Build ssl and ruby as any other C sources making them just another bazel target. This however means you'd need to bazelify their builds (describe and maintain bazel build of otherwise bazel unaware project).
- You can continue further along the path you've started and just (sort of) leave bazel out of it. I.e. for these builds extend the magic and in the build scripts used for instance using deterministic location and perhaps manifest files of what is around (also to make corruption less likely) make it possible to determine that the build has indeed already taken place and you can just collect its previous results.